# Add back arrow to fragment with Navigation Component

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, components

I implemented a basic Navigation component on an app that consist of a **MainActivity** that holds a **Toolbar** (that I have added to have the back arrow functionality) and a fragment container which starts with **Fragment A**. In this fragment I have a button which redirects to a blank **Fragment B**.

I can return to **fragment A** (from **fragment B**) from the bottom Android navigation using Navigation component, but I want to do the same using the back arrow from the toolbar that I have added. 
I implemented the arrow  putting  *setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))* in **Main Activity** and *(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)* on **Fragment B**, but when I tap it it doesn't redirect to **Fragment A** because (I suppose) that the back stack is empty.

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))
}
```

**MainActivity xml**

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
```

**FragmentB**

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
}
```

Added this to remove the default toolbar in **styles.xml**

```
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

In **FragmentB** up button not working
[fragmentB with back not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/se0bu.png)

I want to do that using **Navigation Component**, any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: "In this fragment I have a button which redirects to a blank Fragment B" -- did you use the Navigation component to do that? And did you [add the code that the docs call for](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui?hl=en#action_bar)? In other words, having a [mcve] helps us to help you with your question!

Comment: I go from Fragment A to B using Navigation component following the docs [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation) .Thanks! I uploaded the project to a repo and posted to the question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @MustafaKhaled I could find the correct documentation that is in this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui)

I deleted *setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled* of fragmentB (you don't need to add anything in this fragment).

I leave as it is the code of **styles.xml**.

My new **MainActivity** is like this:

```
private lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    setupNavigation()
}

private fun setupNavigation() {
    val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
    val navController = navHostFragment.navController
    val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.graph).build()
    toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
}
```

Following this way you manage the toolbar behavior through the **Navigation-UI** feature.

---

**UPDATE 28/04/20**

There is an approach simpler than this that doesn't need a toolbar because uses the default one.

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
private lateinit var navController: NavController

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setupNavigation()
}

private fun setupNavigation() {
    val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
    navController = navHostFragment.navController
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.graph).build()
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
```

}

**activity_main.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
```

And my **styles.xml** file is like the default one:

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

The updated repo [link](https://gitlab.com/alefredes/navigationcomponent)

Comment: I didn't know about `androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController` extension method, that was a critical moment and this solved my problem. Thank you!

Just to complete your answer `setupWithNavController` can be called only with first parameter, the second argument has a default value `AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)`

Answer (score 1):

In your **MainActivity**

setup your navigation:

```
    private fun setupNavigation() {
    val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment?
    navController = navHostFragment!!.navController
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration.Builder(setOf(R.id.checklocation,R.id.questions,R.id.news,R.id.profile_tab)).build()
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigation,navController)
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this,navController)
}
```

to enable back arrow be shown and shows the previous destination **override this function**

```
    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    return navController.navigateUp()
}
```

By the way, using navigation component with bottom navigation, we don't have to configure your toolbar, this will be handled by adding above dunctions in your MainActivity.

Comment: What is for you bottomNavigation? Why don't you don't use appBarConfiguration? Thanks @MustafaKhaled

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't understand your question.